# How to send http response into dialog box into angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to send response getting from the back-end to dialog box, when I click on O.K then it will redirect to home page. Same like when we use alert to show response.

It is like,I am updating some **employee information**, after updating, I will give some response like updated_date and updated_by. I want to show these information on dialog box. When I click on O.K button, it will redirect to home page, where all employees listed.

So my question is how to send response to dialog template. I following code I am use alert to show response, but need some dialog window to pop-up like [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LOZOnsVyx3JU5XoKYn74?p=preview)

**Dialog template**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{text}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>    
</div>
```

In my **main controller** I am getting response like

```
$scope.getInfo=function(){     
  var empData={some info}
  $http.post(api,empData)
  .success(function(response, status){
      alert(response);
      $state.go("home");
  });
}
```

Here I am using alert to show the response, instead of alert I want to use dialog box  [some thing like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/LOZOnsVyx3JU5XoKYn74?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from using the angular-ui-bootstrap framework, which implements a [modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) component along many UI components.

That's what the plunker you linked does, by including `//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js` and `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lib ngDialog

http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/

Open a dialog :

```
var dialog = ngDialog.open({
    template: 'externalTemplate.html'
});

dialog.closePromise.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.id + ' has been dismissed.');
});
```

Template :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="externalTemplate.html">
<div class="dialog-contents">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="button" value="OK" ng-click="checkInput() && closeThisDialog('Some value')"/>
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign back-end value to variable which you are using in modal in .success function
$scope.text=empdata;